# GUI in C++ for OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: c++, cocoa, user-interface, g++, osx-mountain-lion

I need to be able to launch a basic GUI from an application written in C++ on Mountain Lion. The obvious ways this would normally be accomplished is through either a cross-platform library like gtk or qt or by launching the c++ code from an objective-c based application. Each has its problem in this case. The application I'm writing uses a class library to connect to a robot. For the application to use the functionality, it must be compiled using the g++ compiler from terminal. The code was never designed to run on anything past Snow Leopard, so it's quite touchy when it comes to compiling and linking. This would seem to preclude my ability to start the C++ code from objective-c written using the xcode ide unless xcode includes compile options that I'm not aware of, at which point other platforms like gtk or qt seem viable. The problem with those is that I haven't been able to get a single one to even compile on Mountain Lion, let along been able to write an application using one. Is this a problem with Mountain Lion/lack of updates? And are there other options for creating the GUI? Maybe a GUI library compatible with Mountain Lion or a way to launch a cocoa-based GUI from the C++ code? It doesn't need to be complex - just a window with some lines drawn in it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how about embedding the C++ code into a Cocoa project as some kind of library or framework, calling into the C++ bits when you need to do robot specific things?

Comment: I explored that for a while, but I haven't been able to find a way to call the specific compiler options needed by the cpp files that control the robot in XCode. I'm not terribly well versed in the xcode ide interface, though, so there may be a way. In case it's helpful, I've been compiling the programs with the following command: g++ `myro-cpp-config --cflags --libs` talent.cpp -o Show -I/opt/X11/include

Comment: Does the code actually use X11 - in that case it has a GUI already

Comment: The library actually does. I didn't even think of that. It looks like X11 should work.